# How to get `Uint8List` from `ImmutableBuffer`?

Tags: flutter, dart, type-conversion

The new Flutter 3.3 deprecates the method `load` of class `ImageProvider` and now some my code became not working because `load` had a parameter `bytes` of type `Uit8List` but `loadBuffer` has a parameter `buffer` of `ImmutableBuffer`.

I used `Uint8List` to decode image using `image` package

```dart
final bytes = img.decodeImage(bytes); // bytes is instance of Uit8List
```

The complete code can be read from the article [Remove a color from an image in Flutter](https://thomasgallinari.medium.com/remove-a-color-from-an-image-in-flutter-36770ac42669) starting from section *4. Decode*.

[image]

And now I need to convert `ImmutableBuffer` to `Uint8List`. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: this needs more eyes 

Comment: I suggest filing a GitHub issue or asking on the Flutter team's Discord server to ask what the intended usage of `ImmutableBuffer` is supposed to be.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121896.